# UDP Packet not captured by Wireshark, but is captured by UDP application

Tags: delphi, udp, wireshark, indy10

I have an application that is designed and working that is receiving UDP broadcasts on a port.  The application has been working just fine, but I have wanted to compare the packets received by the application with a Wireshark capture.  I'm trying to make sure that I'm capturing as many of the packets as possible with minimal data loss.

I initially thought that I'd run Wireshark and compare the raw packets captured against the packets shown in our application.  However, when I run Wireshark, the packets are never captured at the IP layer for that port.  I see other traffic from the server, but I never see Wireshare packets for this specific port.

The application continues to capture the data just fine.  When I look at the IP src/dest fields, the src looks correct, 10.12.10.42, however the destination IP address is 0.0.0.0.  I would have expected something like 255.255.255.255 instead for the destination address.

I don't have access to the application that is broadcasting the data, but I did write a quick sample UDP broadcaster and receiver to make sure I my expectations were correct.  the sample application worked as expected.

Any ideas on why a UDP broadcast would be received by an application, but not show up in a Wireshark capture?  Does Wireshark ignore an address like 0.0.0.0 and not capture it all?

Comment: How this question relates to Delphi and Indy? Also, consider superuser/serverfault.

Comment: It pertains to Delphi in that the application that captures the UDP data is using an Indy10 control.  This Indy10 control captures the data and works while I can't capture anything with Wireshark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wireshark only captures Ethernet frames that are going through an interface you are listening on. Thus, packets destined on loopback addresses are not captured. I would check your machine's routing tables to see where packets are actually going.

Comment: Wireshark does have some support for monitoring loopback adapters.

Comment: From Wireshark wiki : _You can't capture on the local loopback address 127.0.0.1 with a Windows packet capture driver like WinPcap._

Comment: True, you cannot capture from `127.0.0.1` itself, but you can capture from Microsoft's loopback adapter. I've done it before, it works, and it is mentioned on the same Wireshark wiki page you quoted from (http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback). I've also used the `route` technique (since I have a LAN router available), which is also mentioned on the same page, and it works too.