# UDP packets not displayed in Wireshark

Tags: udp, wireshark

I have an embedded jetty server(server1) which sends UDP packets as trigger to receive a message from another server(server2). server1 then waits for a message from server2. This message is then validated and processed further.

From testing the server1, I saw that some times server2 doesnot send messages on receiving a trigger from server1. So I tried analyzing it with Wireshark.

When I gave the capture filter as UDP, it is not showing any packets even though at the server1 I received some packets.

But when I gave the IP address of the server to which request is sent, it is showing some HTTP and TCP packets. 
What could be the reason?

The jetty server(server1) is using DatagramPacket for sending requests. Won't this be sent by UDP itself?

Is there any settings in Wireshark which is preventing from displaying UDP messages?

Comment: UDP is not a handshake protocol so Why it will send back the response? Please keep in mind that UPD is [one way protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)

Comment: the response is sent independently. Not through the same connection/socket. When some message is received,it is processed and mapped to the request sent.

Comment: You mean to say that When you sent some UDP packets to test server then test server creates another request to UDP packets generation server OR some other your defined response collector server which is interprated as a response.Right?

Comment: @freak yes. The first request is a trigger for receiving a message from the test server

Comment: UDP is connectionless protocol. When you a send a data or message, you don't know if it'll get there, it could get lost on the way. There may be corruption while transferring a message.As it is a lossy protocol then I think it is not delivering all packets properly and lost some packets

Comment: that is ok..but why is Wireshark not displaying any UDP packets? That is my question.

Comment: I hope this will help you [UDP Packet not captured by Wireshark, but is captured by UDP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981844/udp-packet-not-captured-by-wireshark-but-is-captured-by-udp-application)

Comment: Also [try by applying filter on UDP traffic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/two-simple-filters-for-wireshark-to-analyze-tcp-and-udp-traffic/3474) , [another link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireshark#Filtering_UDP_packets)

Comment: @freak i think u didnt read my question. I have already tried applying all the capture filters  in that link. Still no udp packets are displayed