# Wireshark doesn't show UDP packets

Tags: networking, udp, wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers

I have checked this [UDP packets not displayed in Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100907/udp-packets-not-displayed-in-wireshark) and this [UDP Packet not captured by Wireshark, but is captured by UDP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981844/udp-packet-not-captured-by-wireshark-but-is-captured-by-udp-application) , but couldn't solve my issue.

I am using Wireshark to observe traffic on an adapter I have connected to some network device- no other traffic than the one I issue is there.

[image]

Then I am using Packet Sender application to send a UDP packet to an IP address I know is on the other side of the adapter (i.e. I am 10.10.10.34, the other device is 10.10.10.1).

[image]

I can correctly ping the other device and ICMP packets are visible in Wireshark. I can sent TCP or SSL packets and see them in Wireshark. Whenever I send UDP packet, it is not seen in Wireshark- I cannot figure out why. All my settings are default ones.

The other thing I suspect that the UDP packet is not sent by the Packet Sender application, but I am not sure how to validate that.

Answer (score 0):

The case was not about Wireshark, but about Packet sender. Binding the IP address as described here solved my problem:

https://github.com/dannagle/PacketSender/issues/158#issuecomment-516481820